# what is the definition of the distance between a complex number with $\mathbb{R}^{+}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

what is the definition of the distance between a complex number with $\mathbb{R}^{+}$? This is
$$
\text{dist}(z,[0,\infty)) \ \ z \in \mathbb{C}?
$$

Comment: That would be $\inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+} |z - t|$.

Comment: It's shorthand for $\text{dist}(\{z\},[0,\infty))$

Comment: @Andrémash The other question you just added is a duplicate of [If $z\in\mathbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$, why $\text{dist }(z, [0,\infty))=:\delta>0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471800/if-z-in-mathbb-c-setminus0-infty-why-textdist-z-0-infty-delta).

Comment: @dxiv f $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus[0,\infty))$ why $\text{dist}(z,[0,\infty)) > 0$?

Comment: 4 up votes in 45 minutes, for as weak a question as this? And an almost identical question on a different account opened within 2 days of this one?

Comment: $d(z, \mathbb{R}^+) = \inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+} |z - t| = \begin{cases} |\text{Im}(z)| &, \text{Re}(z) \geq 0 \\
|z| &, \text{Re}(z) < 0
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This distance ([from a point to a set](https://maths.ucd.ie/courses/mst3013/resources/l/4/mst3013CapFour08.pdf), defined as the shortest distance from $z$ to the positive real axis, as said by @Kaind) can be expressed in the following way.

Let us denote by $L$ the left open half space ($\Re(z)<0$) and by $\mathbb{R^+}$ the positive real axis:

$$d(z,\mathbb{R^+})=\begin{cases}|z|,& z \in L\\ |\Im(z)|,& z \notin L \end{cases}$$

[image]

*The locus of points such that $d(z,\mathbb{R^+})=1.5$.*

Comment: It should be absolute value of imaginary part of z.

Comment: @Kaind you are right. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @JeanMarie How do you do this in GeoGebra?

Comment: @JeanMarie How do you prove this algebraically? Formally.

Comment: @André mash I am out at present. I will answer you soon.

Comment: For the Geogebra programming, I do it by expressing the function as a **polar function** in two steps 1) and 2):                                            1) Definition of the characteristic function of interval $(\pi/2,3 \pi/2)$ by $u(t)=\pi/2 <t<3*\pi/2)  $                      
   2) Definition of the Curve by $Curve(R*(u(t)+(1-u(t))/|\sin(t)|;t),t,0,2*\pi)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie   thank you